# Replacing nginx with uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, uwsgi

It seems that uwsgi is capable of doing almost anything I am using nginx for: serving static content, execute PHP scripts, host python web apps, ...
So (in order to simplify my environment) can I replace nginx + uwsgi with uwsgi without loss of performance/functionality?

Comment: I always used it as a bridge between nginx and python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As they say in the documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/HTTP.html#can-i-use-uwsgi-s-http-capabilities-in-production):

> **Can I use uWSGI’s HTTP capabilities in production?**
>
> If you need a load balancer/proxy it can be a very good idea. It will
>   automatically find new uWSGI instances and can load balance in various
>   ways. If you want to use it as a real webserver you should take into
>   account that serving static files in uWSGI instances is possible, but
>   not as good as using a dedicated full-featured web server. If you host
>   static assets in the cloud or on a CDN, using uWSGI’s HTTP
>   capabilities you can definitely avoid configuring a full webserver.

So yes, uWSGI is slower than a traditional web server.

Besides performance, in a really basic application you're right, uWSGI can do everything the webserver offers.  However, should your application grow/change over time you may find that there are many things the traditional webserver offers which uWSGI does not.

I would recommend setting up deploy scripts in your language of choice (such as [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/index.html) for Python).  I would say my webserver is one of the simplest components to deploy & setup in our applications stack, and the least "needy" - it is rarely on my radar unless I'm configuring a new server.

Comment: could you give me any pointer for using uwsgi with multiple subdomains ?